# Can't show items by sections correctly in recyclerview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am relatively new in kotlin and I would like to know how I can display items by sections, like this: [showing data in sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SSP8.jpg.) . I have two services, one returns the list of section names and the other returns the items for each section.

*So far I did the following, the view is like this:*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="header" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/header_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_productos_seccion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/header_switch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/header_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_title" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*and in my outer adapter I did the following, where I pass a list of sections to the adapter and for each one I consult the service to obtain items and display it:*

```
class SeccionesAdapter(
    var seccionClickAdapter: SeccionClickAdapter,
    private val context: Context,
    var fragment: Fragment,
    var productoViewModel: ProductoViewModel,
    var vm: ClientActivityViewModel
): RecyclerView.Adapter<SeccionesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    interface SeccionClickAdapter{
        fun onSeccionClick(producto: ProductoQryDTO)
    }

    var dataList = emptyList<SeccionQryDTO>()
    var productosLista = ArrayList<ProductoQryDTO>()

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun setData(seccionDTO: SeccionQryDTO) {
            itemView.header_title.text = seccionDTO.nombre
            itemView.header_switch.isChecked = seccionDTO.isSelected?: true
            itemView.list_productos_seccion.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

            if (itemView.header_switch.isChecked) {
                itemView.list_productos_seccion.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                dataFromServer(seccionDTO.id, itemView)
            }

            itemView.header_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> visible(isChecked, seccionDTO.id) }
        }

        fun visible(isChecked: Boolean, idSeccionDTO: Int) {
            if (isChecked) {
                itemView.list_productos_seccion.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                dataFromServer(idSeccionDTO, itemView)

            } else {
                itemView.list_productos_seccion.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    fun dataFromServer(idSeccionDTO: Int, itemView: View) {
        productosLista.clear()
        productoViewModel.getItems(
            idSeccionDTO,
            {
                fragment.activity?.runOnUiThread {
                    productosLista.clear()
                    productosLista.addAll(it.data!!)
                    itemView.list_productos_seccion.adapter = ProductoxSeccionAdapter(context, productosLista, seccionClickAdapter)
                }
            }, {
                Log.e("Error", "", it)
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_header_model, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.setData(dataList[position]!!)
    }

    fun setSecciones(seccionesList : List<SeccionQryDTO>) {
        this.dataList = seccionesList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the application is loaded, sometimes the amount of items that should be for each section is not shown, and when I scroll it begins to make calls to the service, also the elements disappear and it remains blank as shown in this image
[blank space in sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIRDZ.jpg).

Could you help me please? I don't know how I could handle this situation or if I should implement it in some other way

**EDIT**

This is my inner adapter: ProductoxSeccionAdapter

```
class ProductoxSeccionAdapter (
    private val context: Context,
    var listProductos: List<ProductoQryDTO>?,
    var seccionClickAdapter: SeccionesAdapter.SeccionClickAdapter
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoxSeccionAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun setData(producto: ProductoQryDTO) {
            
                itemView.nombreProductoLista.text = producto.nombre
                itemView.descProductoLista.text = producto.detalle
                itemView.precioProductoLista.text = producto.simboloMoneda + producto.precio

            itemView.setOnClickListener { seccionClickAdapter.onSeccionClick(producto) }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_producto_cliente_lista, parent, false))
       
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listProductos!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.setData(listProductos!![position])
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your inner or outer adapter? Can you show both?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I update my question with both adapter's